# Change transparency of tile on mouse over : Unity Tilemaps

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I am creating a game using unity's tilemap system and cant seem to figure this out. I am trying to create an effect where whichever tile the mouse is above, fades a bit, and when the mouse leaves that tile it goes back to normal. Here is my current code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Tilemaps;

public class mouseHoverTiles : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Variables")]
    [SerializeField] private Tilemap groundMap;
    [SerializeField] private Camera mainCam;

    private Vector3Int tilePos;
    private Vector3 mousePos;
    private Tile currentTile;

    void Update()
    {
        mousePos = mainCam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        tilePos = groundMap.WorldToCell(mousePos);

        currentTile = groundMap.GetTile<Tile>(tilePos);

        currentTile.color = new Color(currentTile.color.r, currentTile.color.g,currentTile.color.b, 0.75f);
    } 

}
```

Not only does this script not work, if it was to work then the tiles would never return back to their original transparency.

Comment: Is `currentTile` always `null` or why do you mean the script never works?

Comment: @pixlhero `currentTile.color = new Color(currentTile.color.r, currentTile.color.g,currentTile.color.b, 0.75f);` doesnt seem to do anything.

Comment: hmmm then these are two questions. Maybe if you simplify the setup you can find out why setting the color here doesn't work. Otherwise we need some more info on how your tiles are set up.

Comment: its alright, i found a bettwer way of doing this rather than fading the tilemaps, i just add another "hover tile" above it

Comment: Cool! It would be nice if you added an answer yourself of how you solved it, so others that stumble over this post know what to do.

Comment: I didnt quite solve it, i just found a different way of doing what i wanted in my game